# Is there a way to automatically select text in TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there a way to automatically select or highlight a predetermined area of text on TextView? For instance, I want a specific line on the TextView to be already pre-selected when I start the activity, instead of having the user select that area of text themselves.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is most likely the setSelection, function.

it works like this:

```
EditText edText = findViewById(id);
edText.setSelection(start, stop);
```

The `setSelection()` function takes 2 arguments start and stop, both are ints, its the index of the character where you want the selection to start and the index of the character where you want the selection to end.
for example `setSelection(0,1)` will select the first character of the EditText.

If you want to select a specific String in an EditText you could do something like:

```
EditText edText = findViewById(id);
String lookingFor = "whatever youre looking for";
//You get the index of the first character of the string you're looking for
int start = edText.getText().toString().indexOf(lookingFor);
//You add the string's length to the index so the selection actually selects the 
//whole string.
int stop = start+lookingFor.length();
//You -start- selecting from the 1st character and -stop- at the last character
//Of the string you're looking for.
edText.setSelection(start,stop);
```

Comment: Is there a version of you could use for TextView instead of EditText?

Comment: @calamiteaa Sadly there isn't, you would need to make your own custom class for this.

Comment: There is an answer already doing this class if you'd like to implement it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413404/is-there-any-way-to-programatically-select-text-in-a-textview